# CiviContribute Payment Selection

Tags: civicontribute, civireport, payment-processor, contribution-page

Ok, this is a little difficult to explain, but I'm going to try :)

A customer set up a contribution page for payroll deduction, so they would just select the "Pay Later" payment option, but, for some reason, they didn't select anything for the payment option when setting up the "Contribution Amounts" section. No warnings or anything came up that said it was required to select at least one payment option.

They made the contribution page live and sent it the specific organization for their employees to complete. When we went to pull the report, it had everyone that had completed the contribution form, but the amounts they selected weren't showing at all. Is this because no payment option was selected?

Is it possible to make it a requirement for contribution pages that you have to select some kind of payment option? Whether it be CC or Pay Later?

Hopefully this makes some kind of sense ;)

I really appreciate any info on this one because our customer is frustrated (even though they setup the form without checking with us).

Drupal 7
CiviCRM 4.6.8

If you need any screenshots or anything else, just let me know. :)

Thank You!!
Nicole

Comment: Screenshots would definitely be welcome, as then we can be sure of how the page was set up.

Comment: you must check that paypal processor is selected along with Pay later mode in Amount Tab.

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand and am unclear whether you tried this yourself or not. I presume i don't understand, but here are a couple of factors.

1/ You should not be able to set up a Contribution Page with no options for specifying the amount.

**Contribution Amounts section enabled**
If you want to enable the 'Contribution Amounts section', you need to either 'Allow Other Amounts' and/or enter at least one row in the 'Fixed Contribution Amounts' table.

2/ You should not be able to set up a Contribution page without offering either Payment Processor or Pay Later

**Sorry but we are not able to provide this at the moment.**
A payment processor must be selected for this contribution page (contact the site administrator for assistance).